# How can I connect to vscode's built-in tsserver? What is the port number of vscode tsserver?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I am a novice in developing vscode TS plug-in. How can I connect to vscode's built-in tsserver? What is the port number of vscode tsserver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the [docs](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Standalone-Server-%28tsserver%29#message-format):

> tsserver listens on stdin and writes messages back to stdout.

Comment: It seems that it is only the default behavior rather than the only behavior. I am reading the typescript client implementation of vscode, but it is difficult. Is there any information specific to vscode?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "it seems": the quote given in the answer is taken from the official documentation. It clearly mentions pipes as the means of communication to tsserver. As for VS Code specifics, there's a link to the source code in those docs, I suppose that's the best one can get here.

Comment: I may have confused some things in LSP and tsserver. Indeed, it can only be accessed through pipes. Thank you for your answer.